# What are matter waves made of and what is their speed?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, matter

We know electromagnetic waves are made of oscillating  electric and magnetic fields that can travel at the speed of light without a need for a medium. But, how about matter waves proposed by de Broglie? What are they made of? What is their speed? Do they need a medium to travel?

Comment: Electromagnetic waves ARE electric and magnetic fields that travel at the speed of light. They are not made of anything else than themselves. Electromagnetic waves are perturbations of the electromagnetic field so this last can be thought of as a medium, though it is not really the case. I am afraid there is no real link between electromagnetic waves and de Broglie waves other than the fact that they both are waves.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux why have you written answer in a comment?

Comment: @Umaxo Because I do not answer the four questions asked, I just corrected some mistakes that were made.

Comment: yes but what are matter waves composed of?

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux Which should be written as an answer. This sites is to share knowledge and information. It should no be written in a comment

Comment: Have you studied quantum mechanics (Schrodinger Equation) yet?

Comment: In the general sense, these matter waves are in infinite dimensional Hilbert space. It is an abstract mathematical entity and is not physical. I don't think there is a notion of speed here. There are few very specific examples of systems such as the free particle where you can sort of give meaning to speed/velocity. Moreover, I think you are trying to think of "waves" as physical waves. Wave is a mathematical concept and sound waves or waves in water are few physical realizations modelled by the mathematical concept of a wave.

Answer (score 5):

We don't really look at 'matter waves' as... erm... matter waves anymore. The understanding of the concept has moved on considerably since de Broglie (but textbooks tend to lag behind newer ways of thinking) One physicist is alleged to have quipped, a propos 'matter waves': "*nothing oscillates there*".

Instead it's 'safer' to look at 'matter waves' in the following way.

Suppose we have a subatomic particle. In accordance with  [Schrödinger's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Time-independent_equation) a wave function $\Psi(\mathbf{r})$ is associated with the particle.

[One of Quantum Mechanics' postulates](http://vergil.chemistry.gatech.edu/notes/intro_estruc/node4.html#:%7E:text=The%20total%20wavefunction%20must%20be,result%20of%20this%20antisymmetry%20principle.) (possibly the most important one) is that the wave equation *contains all the information about the particle* there is to know. These observables, like momentum $p$, are obtained by *applying quantum operators* (e.g. $\hat{p}$) to the wave function.

One of the most important observables is the **probability function $P$**, which according to *the Born interpretation* is given by:

$$P(x,\Delta x)=\int_x^{x+\Delta x}\Psi^*\Psi \text{d}x=\int_x^{x+\Delta x}|\Psi|^2 \text{d}x$$

This is for the probability of finding a particle in a $\text{1D}$ domain in a $\Delta x$ interval, located at position $x$.

The *probability density function* is given by:

$$P(x)=|\Psi(x)|^2$$

Below are some probability densities for some quantum states of a [particle in a $1D$ box with infinite potential on the boundaries](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Physical_Chemistry_(McQuarrie_and_Simon)/03%3A_The_Schrodinger_Equation_and_a_Particle_in_a_Box/3.05%3A_The_Energy_of_a_Particle_in_a_Box_is_Quantized):

[image: Probabilities]

**So what is really tangibly 'wavy' here are these *probability densities* $P(x)$.** Rather than 'matter waves', think of them as *probability waves*.

These *probability waves* (and not so much the actual wave functions) explain the interference patterns in *two-slit* electron beam experiments that were responsible for the emergence of the *matter/wave duality* worldview and QM itself in the early 20th  Century.

---

There's also the minor issue of the *unit of measurement* of the wave function. For example for the aforementioned particle in a $\text{1D}$ box the wave functions are given by:

$$\Psi_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}$$
For $n=1,2,3,...$

The unit of measurement is:

$$\mathbf{[\Psi]}=\mathbf{m}^{-1/2}$$

There's no mass in sight, as $\mathbf{m}$ here stands for 'meter'.

Comment: Shouldn't the integration be from x to x+∆x?

Comment: Yes, of course. Edited. Thank you!

Comment: I want to check whether i have understood your answer correct. You are saying that what de Broglie meant was that the probability  curves are sinosoidal look alike , that's what matter waves are?

Comment: No, at that time de Broglie and Schrodinger almost certainly believed in the existence of matter waves. But later research/interpretation claims the only 'waviness' are the probabilities (often actually referred to as *probability amplitudes*)

Comment: i didn't get a notification for your reply . Nevertheless a great answer as as usual.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

E-M waves are not "made" of anything other than the current state of various fields.  Matter waves are similarly not "made" of anything; they simply represent the wavelike behavior of things we treat as solid mass, e.g. electrons.  The whole point of wave-particle duality is that you cannot separate one from the other.

Comment: except that for  subatomic particles what is *waving* is the **probability** of finding the particle at (x,y,z,t), **not** the energy/mass of the particle .over (x,y,z.t)  as with classical elecromagnetic waves, and sound waves ....